# Loginless Client/Server Architecture (iOS)

Tags: tls, certificates, protocols, ios

I'm currently in the phase of planing a project involving loginless service.

Users would be identified by an unique device id created on the client (ios).

What are the security concerns?

- sockets would be wrapped with ssl
- create a private certificate to verify client? (what about someone decompiling the binary and obtaining it?)

any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11657004/372643).

Comment: Bruno, should i delete the question on one site?

Comment: Similar question http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10268/6249

Comment: You can make SSL to validate the website, and random crypted token for authenticating the user, which is encrypted on the server, like sessionid, and stored on the phone. But when your iphone is erased, the local storage is too, so the user would have to re-authenticate, but as long it has the server-side encrypted token, this is OK. I do it and it's OK, I know how many iPhones I serve. I dont identify by Apple Unique ID or anything else and I would never rely on this, as iPhones dont like to be authenticated this way.

Comment: @AndrewSmith so you generate a crypted device token on first connection? How do you re-authenticate if it's not bound to a device specific id? just curious...

Comment: Local cache stores the token until it's cleaned, and with every new request without token, the new is generated, and the cleanup ratio I assume 15% per month. On Android this is working the same way, even in chrome browser. The token is on the phone, so it's completely secure, so until it's there, it is quite high security with even token used as key for decryption if SSL is used, so it's OK just to use cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you can store a device ID on the client, then you can use that as both "username" and "password": *within the SSL tunnel*, the client sends the device ID, which the server looks up in the database. If the device ID is found, voilà! the client is authenticated. Remember that "a client is authenticated" has the same meaning as "no other entity than the client himself could have said that". As long as the "device ID" is client-specific, secret, and unguessable, it is a proper basis for authentication.

Of course, a customer who extracts the data contents of his device and reverse engineers the code will find his own device ID, and will be able to access the server from other computers. That's unavoidable. You cannot enforce usage of a specific client device unless the client device contains a tamper-resistant element (e.g. a [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)), and, apparently, iPhones [do not](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53676/tpm-chip-on-iphone). Certificates or other cryptographic gizmos won't help you there.